# Issue lining bottom shadow up with banner image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to line this bottom shadow up as in the top shadow but I cannot seem to get the firgured out. The only time it collapses is when I remove the line-height or font-size much further down in the css file using Developer Toolbars but of course this affects everything else too. Here's my basic html structure:

```
<div class="banner-image">
  <div class="banner-image-wrapper">
    <div class="shadow-top"></div>
      <a class="header-image">
        <img />
      </a>
    <div class="shadow-bottom"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On the  tag, if I remove the font-size and line-height, everything collapses nicely on itself but I cannot seem to force this just on the  tag.

I know this is going to be a ridiculous issue once it's been solved.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Can you post your CSS? It's difficult to solve a CSS issue without it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is actually pretty simple, you just need to use some clever positioning & take advantage of the parent's box-model:

```
.banner-image{
    position:relative;
}

.shadow-bottom{
    position:absolute;
    height: x;
    bottom: -x;
}
```

Here's the formula you need:

- Take the height of the bottom shadow ( some value x )
- Then make sure the parent of that element has a position of 'relative' (~important~)
- Make the position of the bottom shadow 'absolute'
- Position it at the bottom minus the value of it's height ( -x )

Here's a jsFiddle illustrating the effect: http://jsfiddle.net/k7CmJ/

Comment: Or there is absolute positioning ;) Thanks Vita

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but for anybody else looking for an answer to this, where absolute positioning won't work, setting display:block on the img tag will get rid of that space:

```
.header-image > img {
    display:block;
}
```

Normally an image is an inline block, and because it's inline, white-space around it is preserved.

Here is the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/3Kd3f/

And here is the exact same code, only with display:block added to the img tag: http://jsfiddle.net/3Kd3f/1/